# Solve $37x^2-113y^2=n$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Prove that if these equations :
$$37a^2\equiv n\pmod {113}\tag 1$$
$$-113b^2\equiv n\pmod {37}\tag 2$$
$$37c^2\equiv 113\pmod {n}\tag 3$$
have integer solutions, then the equation 
$$37x^2-113y^2=n$$
has integer solutions.

Comment: Why is there no solution? Could the "mod n" be responsible?

Comment: @JoeHobbit $-82c^2\equiv 23 \pmod 1$ is solvable. The equations(1)(2)(3) are just to rule out p-adic restrictions.

Comment: How does (3) follow from $37x^2 \equiv 113y^2 \pmod{n}$ ? Or maybe that's part of the question.

Comment: @coffeemath Thank you,I have edited my question.(remove "iff")

Comment: Ah, so the easy part is gone :(

Comment: @Daniel Fischer I have to say very much to keep the easy part..

Comment: @DanielFischer By the easy part, do you mean that from $37x^2-113y^2=n$ one may easily derive there is $c$ with $37c^2 \equiv 113 \pmod{n}$ ? If so I'd like to see that (maybe it's easy).

Comment: Where did you find this?

Comment: @Will Jagy I find this with my computer. I try all the numbers $1<n<200$ which satisfy (1)(2)(3) and find that the last equation always has solutions.

Comment: @coffeemath Not exactly that. Start with $37\cdot 2^2 - 113 \cdot 1^2 = 35$. Now find a prime $p > 7$ with $\left(\frac{37\cdot 113}{p}\right) = -1$. Take $13$ for example. Now $37x^2 - 113 y^2 = 35\cdot 13^2$ obviously has the solution $x = 26,\, y = 13$. But $37c^2 \equiv 113 \pmod{13}$ has no solution, hence a fortiori $37c^2 \equiv 113 \pmod{35\cdot 13^2}$ doesn't have one.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for that comment. I thought something was fishy about that step, and your example shows the step is not automatic.

Comment: @Hecke There was a gap in my proof because I did not take into account the fact that $16724$ is not a fundamental discriminant.  I think I fixed it.  By the way, does your nickname have anything to do with Erich Hecke?

Comment: @Michael Wijaya I need some time to understand your proof, because I do not learn binary quadratic form yet. My nickname "Hecke" is to express my respect for Erich Hecke, I'm studing his lecture now.

Comment: @Hecke One of my favorite quotes: "To improve upon Hecke, in a treatment along classical lines of the theory of algebraic numbers, would be a futile and impossible task." --- André Weil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Disclaimer

This is not a complete answer to your question because it only works when $n$ is not divisible by $37$ or $113$.  I think we should be able to go around this restriction without too much more work, but here is what I have so far.

## Introduction

By a primitive integral [binary quadratic form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_quadratic_form), I mean one whose coefficients are relatively prime.

The first thing I did was to find out the number of equivalence classes of primitive integral binary quadratic forms of discriminant $D = -4 \cdot 37 \cdot (-113) = 16724$.  The reduction algorithm is not too complicated, but I used the online applet [here](http://www.numbertheory.org/php/classnopos0.html) because the discriminant is rather big.  It says that there are two equivalence classes, with $x^2 + 128xy -85y^2$ and $5x^2 + 122xy - 92y^2$ serving as possible representatives.

It is important to note that the applet disregards non-primitive forms.  This is relevant because $16724$ is not a [fundamental discriminant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_discriminant).  There are in fact two more equivalence classes of non-primitive forms with discriminant $16724$ --- basically primitive forms with discriminant $4181$ scaled by $2$.  We will come back to this when we carry out the second part of our plan.

This means that for any given primitive integral binary quadratic form $AX^2 + BXY + CY^2$ of discriminant $16724$, we can find a matrix $M \in GL_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ such that
$$
 M^{t} \begin{pmatrix} A & \frac{B}{2} \\ \frac{B}{2} & C \end{pmatrix} M = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 64 \\ 64 & -85 \end{pmatrix}  \ \  \text{or} \ \  \begin{pmatrix} 5 & 61 \\ 61 & -92 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
We can also think of this as there being an integrally invertible change of variables
$$
 \begin{pmatrix} X \\ Y \end{pmatrix} = M \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}
$$
which will turn $AX^2 + BXY + CY^2$ into one of the two representative forms.  In particular, the set of integers represented by a primitive form of discriminant $16724$ coincides with the corresponding set of one of the two representative forms.

So here is our plan to exploit the congruence conditions given in the question:

1. Find a way to distinguish numbers represented by the two representative forms.
2. Show that $n$ is represented by some primitive form of discriminant $16724$

## First part of the plan

By completing the squares, we can write
$$
x^2 + 128xy -85y^2 = (x + 64y)^2 - (37 \cdot 113) y^2.
$$
If $n$ is represented by that form, we know from reducing modulo $37$ or $113$ that $n$ is a square modulo both primes.  We can do something similar for the other form to get
$$
5x^2 + 122xy - 92y^2 = \frac{1}{5} \left\{ (5x+61y)^2 - (37 \cdot 113)y^2 \right\}.
$$
So if $n$ is represented by the second form, $5n$ must be a square modulo both $37$ and $113$.  If we assume that $n$ is relatively prime to $37$ (respectively $113$), we can also conclude that $n$ is not a square modulo $37$ (respectively $113$).

To summarize, given an integer which is not divisible by both $37$ and $113$ we can immediately pick out one of the two forms which cannot possibly represent that integer.

## Second part of the plan

If we can find integers $B$ and $C$ such that $nx^2 + Bxy + Cy^2$ is primitive (this is important) and has discriminant $16724$, then we have basically showed that $n$ is represented by one of the two forms listed by the applet.  When can we find such $B$ and $C$?  We need
$$
B^2 - 4nC = 16724 = 2^2 \cdot 37 \cdot 113.
$$
In other words, we need to solve the congruence equation $B^2 \equiv 2^2 \cdot 37 \cdot 113 \pmod{4n}$.  This is equivalent to solving $B_0^2 \equiv 37 \cdot 113 \pmod{n}$.

If we assume that $n$ is not divisible by $113$, then the conditions stated in the question implies that the congruence equation is solvable.  More specifically, the third equation implies that $(37 \cdot 113)c^2 \equiv 113^2 \pmod{n}$ has a solution in $c$.  The only possible common factor between $c$ and $n$ is $113$, so by our assumption, $c$ is relatively prime to $n$.  Therefore
$$
(113 \cdot c^{-1})^2 \equiv 37 \cdot 113 \pmod{n}
$$
gives us a solution of the congruence equation we need to construct a form of discriminant $16724$ which represents $n$.

How can be be sure that the form we constructed is primitive?  If $n$ is even, what is there to prevent both $B$ and $C$ to be even as well?  We will deal with this issue by showing that subject to congruence conditions given in the question, an even $n$ is never represented by any of the two non-primitive forms of discriminant $16724$.

We can carry out an analysis similiar to what we did above to show that if $\frac{n}{2}$ is represented by a form of discriminant $4181$, then we must be able to solve the congruence equation
$$
B^2 \equiv 37 \cdot 113 \pmod{4 \cdot \frac{n}{2}}.
$$
There is no hope if $n$ is divisible by $4$, because $37 \cdot 113$ is simply not a square modulo $8$.  So the question now is whether the three congruence equations forces an even $n$ to be divisible by $4$.

Let us assume to the contrary, that there is an even $n$ which is not divisible by $4$.  We will write $n = 2n_{0}$, where $2 \nmid n_{0}$.  We can check that
$$
\left( \frac{37a^2}{113} \right) = \left( \frac{-113b^2}{37} \right),
$$
so $n$ is simultaneously a square or a non-square modulo $37$ and $113$.  Therefore
$$
\left( \frac{2n_{0}}{113} \right) = \left( \frac{2n_{0}}{113} \right) \implies \left( \frac{n_{0}}{113} \right) = - \left( \frac{n_{0}}{37} \right) \implies \left( \frac{113}{n_{0}} \right) = - \left( \frac{37}{n_{0}} \right)
$$
by [properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_symbol#Properties) of the Jacobi symbol, with the last implication exploiting the fact that $n_{0}$ is odd.  This contradicts the third congruence equation in the question.

I think this is the only section where I assume that $37 \nmid n_{0}$.

## Putting everything together

We have seen that if $113 \nmid n$, then $n$ is primitively represented by one of the two forms.  Now the question is which one.  From the first part of the plan, we know that this depends on whether $n$ is a square modulo $113$.  Since $37$ is not a square modulo $113$, the first equation in the question implies that $n$ is not a square modulo $113$.  Therefore $n$ must be an integer represented by $5x^2 + 122xy - 92y^2$.

To finish things off, we just need to verify that $37x^2 - 113y^2$ is equivalent to $5x^2 + 122xy - 92y^2$.  It suffices to check, that $1$ is represented by $x^2 + 128xy -85y^2$ but not by $37x^2 - 113y^2$.

## Other comments

We cannot always separate classes of forms using only congruence conditions on the integers they represent, but this modest idea is the starting point of genus theory.  Dirichlet's [*Lectures on Number Theory*](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=HMATH-16) has a very down-to-earth introduction to this.  If you prefer a more modern presentation in terms of abstract algebra, you may want to also look at Flath's [*Introduction to Number Theory*](http://amzn.com/047160836X).

The congruence conditions given in the question turn out to be sufficient to guarantee the existence of a form of discriminant $16724$ whose first coefficient is $n$.  Suppose we do not have any of those congruence conditions, and we want to try to classify integers $n$ represented by $37x^2 - 113y^2$.  It would be nice if we could say that there is a form of the same discriminant with $n$ as the first coefficient;  as we have seen above, this immediately gives some necessary conditions that $n$ must satisfy.

There is a standard trick which does just this, assuming that $n$ is primitively represented.  An integer $n$ is primitively represented by a form $ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$ if there are relatively prime integers $x_0$ and $y_0$ such that $ax_0^2 + bx_0 y_0 + cy_0^2 = n$.  Since $x_{0}$ and $y_{0}$ are relatively prime, we can find integers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $x_{0} \beta - y_{0} \alpha = 1$.  Now we have
$$
\begin{pmatrix} x_{0} & \alpha \\ y_{0} & \beta \end{pmatrix}^{t} \begin{pmatrix} a & \frac{b}{2} \\ \frac{b}{2} & c \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_{0} & \alpha \\ y_{0} & \beta \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} n & \ast \\ \ast & \ast \end{pmatrix}.
$$