# What's the set p,if $37x^2-113y^2=p$ is solvable,with p a prime

Tags: prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

if $37x^2-113y^2=p$ is solvable.with p a odd prime. What's the set of all $p$? Does it have a formula?

Comment: That equation doesn't even make sense if $p$ is a _set_. It needs to be a _number_.

Comment: I think he means "the set of all $p$". $\exists$ a related post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442138/solve-37x2-113y2-n.

Comment: I was thinking that the solution goes something along the lines of Bezout's Identity and congruences modulo 4.

Comment: I interpret the question to mean, find all prime $p$ such that there exists at least one ordered pair $(x,y)$ of integers that satisfies $37x^2 - 113y^2 = p$.  In other words, find all primes $p$ expressible in the form $37x^2 - 113y^2$ for integers $x, y$.

Comment: Put x=0 once and y=0 once you get two prime numbers.

Answer (score 2):

A book I recommend for this material is [Duncan A. Buell, Binary Quadratic Forms](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183555923) and [USED COPIES](http://www.abebooks.com/servlet/SearchResults?an=buell&sts=t&tn=binary%20quadratic%20forms).

This discriminant has class number two. This form is alone in its genus. Also, the principal form represents $-1,$ so there is no distinction between representing $p$ and $-p.$ This form represents $37$ and $113$ and all primes that are nonresidues $\pmod {37}$ and $\pmod {113},$ such as $5,17,19,23,29,\ldots.$ Note that $(2| 113) = 1.$

There are just two classes in this discriminant, and they are in different genera, the form $37 x^2 - 113 y^2$ and the principal form $x^2 - 4181 y^2. $ As 
$$ 489181478614821790^2 - 4181 \cdot 7565365622404889^2 = -1,  $$  any number $n$ is represented by one of these forms if and only if $-n$ is represented by the same form.

Here are the Lagrange cycles. The first coefficient in each triple is a number that is represented primitively. A primitive representation is one with $\gcd(x,y)=1.$ For example, we can solve $x^2 - 4181 y^2 = 4$ with both $x,y$ odd, so that $\gcd(x,y)=1$ in this case, as 
$$  985522780227^2 - 4181 \cdot 15241460455^2 = 4.  $$
Alright, for each triple $\langle a,b,c \rangle$ in the cycles below, the indicated forms are "reduced." The discriminant is $\Delta = 4 \cdot 37 \cdot 113 = 16724$ so that $\sqrt \Delta \approx 129.32.$ It follows from the definition of reduced that $|a|, b, |c| < 130.$ It is a theorem of Lagrange, Theorem 85 on page 111 of [Introduction to the Theory of Numbers by Leonard Eugene Dickson](http://www.abebooks.com/servlet/SearchResults?an=dickson&sts=t&tn=introduction%20to%20the%20theory%20of%20numbers), that any number $n$ that is primitively represented by one of these forms, with $|n| < (1/2) \sqrt \Delta \approx 64.66,$ occurs as the first coefficient of a form in that cycle.

```
=========================================
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./indefCycle 37 0 -113

  0  form             37           0        -113  delta      0
  1  form           -113           0          37  delta      1
  2  form             37          74         -76


          -1          -1
           0          -1

To Return  
          -1           1
           0          -1

0  form   37 74 -76   delta  -1
1  form   -76 78 35   delta  2
2  form   35 62 -92   delta  -1
3  form   -92 122 5   delta  25
4  form   5 128 -17   delta  -7
5  form   -17 110 68   delta  1
6  form   68 26 -59   delta  -1
7  form   -59 92 35   delta  3
8  form   35 118 -20   delta  -6
9  form   -20 122 23   delta  5
10  form   23 108 -55   delta  -2
11  form   -55 112 19   delta  6
12  form   19 116 -43   delta  -2
13  form   -43 56 79   delta  1
14  form   79 102 -20   delta  -5
15  form   -20 98 89   delta  1
16  form   89 80 -29   delta  -3
17  form   -29 94 68   delta  1
18  form   68 42 -55   delta  -1
19  form   -55 68 55   delta  1
20  form   55 42 -68   delta  -1
21  form   -68 94 29   delta  3
22  form   29 80 -89   delta  -1
23  form   -89 98 20   delta  5
24  form   20 102 -79   delta  -1
25  form   -79 56 43   delta  2
26  form   43 116 -19   delta  -6
27  form   -19 112 55   delta  2
28  form   55 108 -23   delta  -5
29  form   -23 122 20   delta  6
30  form   20 118 -35   delta  -3
31  form   -35 92 59   delta  1
32  form   59 26 -68   delta  -1
33  form   -68 110 17   delta  7
34  form   17 128 -5   delta  -25
35  form   -5 122 92   delta  1
36  form   92 62 -35   delta  -2
37  form   -35 78 76   delta  1
38  form   76 74 -37   delta  -2
39  form   -37 74 76   delta  1
40  form   76 78 -35   delta  -2
41  form   -35 62 92   delta  1
42  form   92 122 -5   delta  -25
43  form   -5 128 17   delta  7
44  form   17 110 -68   delta  -1
45  form   -68 26 59   delta  1
46  form   59 92 -35   delta  -3
47  form   -35 118 20   delta  6
48  form   20 122 -23   delta  -5
49  form   -23 108 55   delta  2
50  form   55 112 -19   delta  -6
51  form   -19 116 43   delta  2
52  form   43 56 -79   delta  -1
53  form   -79 102 20   delta  5
54  form   20 98 -89   delta  -1
55  form   -89 80 29   delta  3
56  form   29 94 -68   delta  -1
57  form   -68 42 55   delta  1
58  form   55 68 -55   delta  -1
59  form   -55 42 68   delta  1
60  form   68 94 -29   delta  -3
61  form   -29 80 89   delta  1
62  form   89 98 -20   delta  -5
63  form   -20 102 79   delta  1
64  form   79 56 -43   delta  -2
65  form   -43 116 19   delta  6
66  form   19 112 -55   delta  -2
67  form   -55 108 23   delta  5
68  form   23 122 -20   delta  -6
69  form   -20 118 35   delta  3
70  form   35 92 -59   delta  -1
71  form   -59 26 68   delta  1
72  form   68 110 -17   delta  -7
73  form   -17 128 5   delta  25
74  form   5 122 -92   delta  -1
75  form   -92 62 35   delta  2
76  form   35 78 -76   delta  -1
77  form   -76 74 37   delta  2
78  form   37 74 -76


  form   37 x^2  + 74 x y  -76 y^2 

minimum was   5rep   x = 3   y = 4 disc   16724 dSqrt 129.32130528  M_Ratio  12.21622
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
-204735119173764075454348029897491261  -562527184697324302711441753879159120
-273861918865802621056886117020116940  -752458956905369317568120263937725141
=========================================

=========================================
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ 
    jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ 
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./indefCycle 1 0 -4181

  0  form              1           0       -4181  delta      0
  1  form          -4181           0           1  delta     64
  2  form              1         128         -85


          -1         -64
           0          -1

To Return  
          -1          64
           0          -1

0  form   1 128 -85   delta  -1
1  form   -85 42 44   delta  1
2  form   44 46 -83   delta  -1
3  form   -83 120 7   delta  17
4  form   7 118 -100   delta  -1
5  form   -100 82 25   delta  4
6  form   25 118 -28   delta  -4
7  form   -28 106 49   delta  2
8  form   49 90 -44   delta  -2
9  form   -44 86 53   delta  2
10  form   53 126 -4   delta  -31
11  form   -4 122 115   delta  1
12  form   115 108 -11   delta  -10
13  form   -11 112 95   delta  1
14  form   95 78 -28   delta  -3
15  form   -28 90 77   delta  1
16  form   77 64 -41   delta  -2
17  form   -41 100 41   delta  2
18  form   41 64 -77   delta  -1
19  form   -77 90 28   delta  3
20  form   28 78 -95   delta  -1
21  form   -95 112 11   delta  10
22  form   11 108 -115   delta  -1
23  form   -115 122 4   delta  31
24  form   4 126 -53   delta  -2
25  form   -53 86 44   delta  2
26  form   44 90 -49   delta  -2
27  form   -49 106 28   delta  4
28  form   28 118 -25   delta  -4
29  form   -25 82 100   delta  1
30  form   100 118 -7   delta  -17
31  form   -7 120 83   delta  1
32  form   83 46 -44   delta  -1
33  form   -44 42 85   delta  1
34  form   85 128 -1   delta  -128
35  form   -1 128 85   delta  1
36  form   85 42 -44   delta  -1
37  form   -44 46 83   delta  1
38  form   83 120 -7   delta  -17
39  form   -7 118 100   delta  1
40  form   100 82 -25   delta  -4
41  form   -25 118 28   delta  4
42  form   28 106 -49   delta  -2
43  form   -49 90 44   delta  2
44  form   44 86 -53   delta  -2
45  form   -53 126 4   delta  31
46  form   4 122 -115   delta  -1
47  form   -115 108 11   delta  10
48  form   11 112 -95   delta  -1
49  form   -95 78 28   delta  3
50  form   28 90 -77   delta  -1
51  form   -77 64 41   delta  2
52  form   41 100 -41   delta  -2
53  form   -41 64 77   delta  1
54  form   77 90 -28   delta  -3
55  form   -28 78 95   delta  1
56  form   95 112 -11   delta  -10
57  form   -11 108 115   delta  1
58  form   115 122 -4   delta  -31
59  form   -4 126 53   delta  2
60  form   53 86 -44   delta  -2
61  form   -44 90 49   delta  2
62  form   49 106 -28   delta  -4
63  form   -28 118 25   delta  4
64  form   25 82 -100   delta  -1
65  form   -100 118 7   delta  17
66  form   7 120 -83   delta  -1
67  form   -83 46 44   delta  1
68  form   44 42 -85   delta  -1
69  form   -85 128 1   delta  128
70  form   1 128 -85


  form   1 x^2  + 128 x y  -85 y^2 

minimum was   1rep   x = 1   y = 0 disc   16724 dSqrt 129.32130528  M_Ratio  16724
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
-4889935136556757385809512072000521  -629142246043060075400954593154322700
-7401673482859530298834759919462620  -952304140942576635636658781763215881
=========================================
```

Comment: you mean $37x^2-113y^2=-5$is representable?but$37x^2-113y^2=-1$ is unsolvable.

Comment: @wsc, You're Alive! I meant rather more than that.